# Looping through a vector and finding a maximum sum of values with fixed number of indices

Tags: rust

I need to:

1. Loop through an array of eight values (`d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`).
2. Sum the first three (indexes: 0, 1, 2) items (`'sum1'`) and the last five items (indexes: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) (`'sum2'`), and perform an operation with those derived sums (`abs(3*sum1 + 5*sum2)`.
3. Do this operation for eight different configurations. The next configuration would be to sum of three items at 1, 2, 3 indices, while the sum of five would be under 4, 5, 6, 7, 0. Under each new configuration the sum of items shifts one index to the right.
4. From this, eight values in a vector or something else should be obtained from performing the `abs(3*sum1 + 5*sum2)` expression that each contain different `sum1` and `sum2` due to difference in indices.
5. Among those eight values I need to find the maximum.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking for help, you should provide a [MCVE]. The code you have provided is both too big and not big enough. It doesn't include the imports you are using, but it's questionable whether those imports are even needed for the core of your question. Additionally, the provided code isn't even *syntactically valid*, which means that it didn't come from code that you have tried to compile once.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretend you have an infinite sequence of numbers, repeating itself. It makes the problem much easier:

```
fn main() {
    let d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let mut numbers = d.iter().cycle();

    let max = (0..d.len())
        .map(|_| {
            let sum1: i32 = numbers.by_ref().take(3).sum();
            let sum2: i32 = numbers.by_ref().take(5).sum();

            // Skip one so the next iteration is offset by one
            numbers.next();

            (sum1, sum2)
        })
        .map(|(sum1, sum2)| i32::abs(3 * sum1 + 5 * sum2))
        .max();

    println!("{:?}", max);
}
```

Comment: this is awesome!! Thank you!!